# Soft question: A good book for introduction to Lie group book

Tags: lie-groups

I am taking next semester introduction lie groups. 
I was wondering what do you guys think what book should I use for this course.

Comment: what's your background? what book is required by your course?

Comment: I took abstract algebra,analysis,and linear algebra course so far they didn't post a book so that is why I want a good book to use along side with lecture notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try [Brian Hall: Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441923136). This book is very nice and slow paced. It also isn't too terribly expensive. The book requires Linear Algebra and abstract algebra. It would also hepl to know a bit of topology. I don't think you can find a good resource that doesn't require this though.

---

You could also take a look at the notes that James Milne has put on [his website](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ala.html). These might be a bit harder (maybe not).